# Call method from pouchdb sync

Tags: pouchdb

I have a class setup like this

```
class FinanceDB {

  constructor() {
    this.PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
    this.db = new this.PouchDB('fin'); //8080
    this.remoteDB = new this.PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/rfin');

    this.db.sync(this.remoteDB, {
      live: true,
      retry: true
    }).on('change', function (change) {

      console.log('yo, something changed!');
      this.dosomething();

    }).on('error', function (err) {
      console.log("error", err);
      // yo, we got an error! (maybe the user went offline?)
    })
  };

  dosomething() {
    console.log('what now?');
  };
}
```

When the database changes, the console reads 'yo, something changed!' as expected. But my class method is never run and I don't get any errors. How do I call a method from inside pouchdb sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a function in the callback here:

```
on('change', function (change) {

  console.log('yo, something changed!');
  this.dosomething();

})
```

You are getting the dynamic `this` which is detached from your class in the callback.

In Es6, you can now just switch to an Arrow function to get 'this' to be lexically scoped:

```
on('change', (change) => {

  console.log('yo, something changed!');
  this.dosomething();

})
```

In the past, the usual method was to create a new variable set equal to `this` before setting up the callback:

```
var that = this;
...
on('change', function (change) {

  console.log('yo, something changed!');
  that.dosomething();

})
```

A comparison of the arrow and regular function in a [JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/t6Lfeqq0/1/).